# gulp-clean: Cannot delete files outside the current working directory

Tags: node.js, angular, gulp

When in my Angular2 project I run the command:

```
gulp clean
```

I am facing the following error even if I used:

```
gulp clean --force but no success.
```

Please can anyone explain **what is the root cause of this issue or what is wrong with this?** I will highly appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can set `force` option true when calling `clean()` in your `gulpfile.js`.
For example:

```
gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return gulp.src(
    ['***your filename/folder here***'],
    {read: false}
  )
    .pipe(clean({force: true})); // this is force option
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to set force to true inside your gulp task

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean